# Spring Boot, define timezone for Json and java.time.* globally

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.3, Spring Data REST, HATEOAS to create a REST service.
I use `java.time.*` date/times in my application and I'm storing that in UTC format in the database.
I want to follow best practice and return UTC dates in my REST endpoints.

Using @JsonFormat I'm able to accomplish to that:

```
@JsonFormat(timezone = "UTC", pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;
```

I would like to avoid to annotate all my beans with that, and I would prefer to have a global configuration.
According to [this enhancemente request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4217), I was able to solve 50% of my problem with this configuration:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializers(
                    new LocalDateTimeSerializer(new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").toFormatter()));
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializers(new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(
                    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").toFormatter()));
        }

    };
}
```

This fix the pattern problem but not the timezone problem. My timezone continue to remain the local timezone.
Is there a graceful way to set the timezone of JSON serializer to UTC like the property `spring.jackson.time-zone=UTC` that unfortunately work just for `java.util.time`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to set the timezone of your formatter.

See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/09f0957b3ac9711fb9dd86f77ad69c549401074f/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/_JacksonConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_FIXED_FORMAT =
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").withZone(ZoneId.of("Z"));

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder) {
                jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.serializers(new ZonedDateTimeSerializer(ISO_FIXED_FORMAT));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine...but only if the field is a ZonedDateTime. What if I wanted make it works also with LocalDateTime? Now fields that are LocalDateTime are returned still in my local timezone ("createdDate": "2017-07-04T08:58:04") instead ZonedTimeZone are returned right ("lastModifiedDate": "2017-07-04T06:58:04.000Z")

Comment: I don't think LocalDateTime has the concept of a timezone. Have you tried adding the same kind of serializer as for ZonedDateTime using withZone() in the formatter ?

Comment: I tried but the time is not in UTC, remains in my timezone. I see LocalDateTime has not the concept of a timezone but I would like the time is returned in UTC. Some chances to do that?

Comment: LocalDateTime is neither in your timezone nor in UTC : it just doesn't have a timezone. The value you read "2017-07-04T08:58:04" depends on how you created the LocalDateTime object.

Comment: That said, are you sure you want to use ZonedDateTime and LocalDateTime ? For event timestamping, I would recommend using Instant  instead.

Comment: What you said make sense.I want to use java.time.* because seems a good thing to do in a new project. My LocalDateTime are created when I create the bean and it stored in the database like the time was UTC, so Hibernate in some way do the conversion. So I wanted do the same when the value is returned in REST services. If Hibernate is able to convert that I guess there is a way to do also using some setting. Why should I use timestamping insted of new java.*time classes?Also jHipster use ZonedLocalDateTime. Thanks

Comment: The way Hibernate stores the data depends on the underlying database and the type of column (eg. timestamp vs timestamp with timezone). If when you read directly the data in the DB, it's in UTC, it means Hibernate uses the system/JVM timezone to convert. And Hibernate will use the same timezone when extracting from the DB. In the end, you read the same LocalDateTime value that you wrote which is as expected. But your LocalDateTime still doesn't have a timezone.

Comment: When I say use "Instant", I mean [java.time.Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) which is now supported in Jhipster and used everywhere an event time is stored (JHipster team member speaking)

Comment: Wanna take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378146/why-is-localdatetime-not-serialized-as-utc-with-time-zone ? I think I'm running in the same issue. I use `LocalDateTime` in my entities which hibernate translates as `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. All that works so far but the serialization from server to client is not as I'd expect it.

Comment: You can use `jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.timeZone("UTC");`